# how to setup a service that will forward pop3 emails to another pop3 server

Tags: synchronization, pop3

I have a pop3 account only accessible from the localhost ip (its a gatewate service running locally and cannot be exposed outside of the machine)

I would like to setup a service  (its a windows  7 machine) that will retrieve any email on that account and either  forward or copy it to a second account.

so far my Google Mojo failed to find a satisfactory solution,  but there has to be such a tool around ,  anybody  can help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules capabilities of Outlook Express appears to be able to do what you are seeking.

There is also the Mercury/32 email server which runs under Windows. It can definitely accomplish what you described.